# Como moficar este package de swipe button?

Tags: flutter, dart, packages

una consulta estoy usando este paquete de flutter

[Enlace del paquete](https://pub.dev/packages/swipe_button)

Es un paquete que me ayuda en el swipe button para deslizar mi boton de izquierda a derecha y la verdad que me ayudo bastante ya que he reutilizado codigo, pero el punto esque al deslizarlo de izquierda a derecha y llega al final del lado derecho este boton se queda en el lado derecho y la verdad yo quisiera que cuando llegue a la derecha si no se cumple una condicion se vuelva automaticamente a la izquierda de donde estava.

he intentado usando la propiedad `initialPosition`  del `SwipeButton` y en esta almacenarle el valor que tengo como propiedad de mi clase mas arriba osea una variable llamada `var posicionThumb = SwipePosition.SwipeLeft;` y cambiar con `setState` y volver a iniciar cuando se cumple la condicion de volver a la izquierda pero nada no me funciona aqui le pongo mi codigo:

```
    class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

   var posicionThumb = SwipePosition.SwipeLeft;
    ....
    ....

     Widget _canjearPuntos(){

       return SwipeButton(  
                           initialPosition: this.posicionThumb,
                           thumb: Row(
                           mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                           children: <Widget>[
                             Align(
                                 widthFactor: 0.90,
                                 child: Icon(
                                   Icons.arrow_forward,
                                   size: 40.0,
                                   color: Colors.brown,
                                 )) //esto agregue
                           ],
                         ),
                         content: Center(
                           child: Text(
                             "Deslizar para canjear",
                             style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                           ),
                         ),
                         onChanged: (result) {
                           if (result == SwipePosition.SwipeRight) {
                             print("Deslizado");  
                             //este setState supuestamente deveria hacer 
                             // que la posicion del boton vuelva al lado izquierdo pero no 
                              //pasa nada
                             this.setState( () {
                                  this.posicionThumb = SwipePosition.SwipeLeft;
                             });

                           } else {
                             print("Devuelto atras");
                           }
                         },
                       );

             }
   .....
   ....
 }
```

La verdad no se que mas puedo hacer entre la clase de  `SwipeButton` presionando `command+click` obviamente en la case y quise urgetearlo pero no se en que parte lo llama o como es la cosa.

muchas gracias amigos espero su ayuda. aqui le pongo una foto de como queda cuando deslizo de izquierda a derecha y este se queda en la derecha sin volver atras y es como NO quiero que sea segun mi condicion de codigo.

Muchas gracias amigos.

[image: Imagen de como queda al deslizar hacia derecha mi SwipeButton]

Comment: veo que este package tiene limitaciones , voy a modificarlo y te paso el código

Comment: Ya amigo muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok ,ya modifiqué el package, enviaré un Pull request al autor para que incorpore los cambios, de todas maneras ya puedes usarlo apuntando a mi repo.

En tu `pubspec.yaml` úsalo así :

```yaml
  swipe_button:
    git: git://github.com/diegoveloper/swipe_button.git
```

Ejecuta :

```
flutter pub upgrade
```

Para refrescar los cambios.

Declara el SwipeController  :

```dart
final swipeController = SwipeController();
```

Asígnalo a tu `SwipeButton`

```dart
SwipeButton(
            swipeController: swipeController,
            ...
```

Y ya puedes usar el método reset.

```
swipeController.reset();

// o con la duración que desees:

swipeController.reset(duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 100));
```

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo me sirvio.